Android Automotive: Loading state with invalidate and onGetTemplate
I've got following simple use-case:
Open a screen with a simple Pane template, fetch data from a server and display the result in the pane template. During fetching a loading spinner should be displayed.

I use a ViewModel with a uiState. Every time the state changes "invalidate()" is called.

Loading state is set -> invalidate() is called -> onGetTemplate() is called -> Loading spinner is displayed
Data state is set (with a short delay) -> invalidate() is called -> onGetTemplate() is not called directly. It takes about 10 seconds until onGetTemplate() gets finally called and the data is displayed to the user.


Can anyone explain this to me? I can't find any information about this phenomenon. 
I understand that they don't want us to update the UI too often, but this doesn't make any sense with a loading state!

The problem seems to be the emulator.
If a different emulator than "Automotive (1024p landscape)" is used the problem does not occur. The strange thing is, that the issue was not there from the beginning. Even after a re-creation of the emulator the problem still exists.

We're seeing the same issue, but it only seems to occur on devices/emulators running AA with Android 12L. We see the same problem on "Automotive (1024p landscape)", Polestar 2 and Volvo XC40 emulators, all of which are running 12L. Devices running on Android 13 doesn't seem to have this issue (tested on "Automotive (1080p landscape)", "Automotive portrait", Honda IVI-System).
We are in the process of starting to test on devices in cars, but have gotten worrying feedback that the UI is really slow there as well.
It's suspicious that it seems to be exactly 10s here as well....
